# Can not acquire value from Hashtable

Tags: java, regex, string, split, hashmap

I wrote the following Java code,

```
try {
    String str = "";
    Hashtable< String, String> table = new Hashtable< String, String>();
    fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\station.txt");// FileInputStream
    isr = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    br = new BufferedReader(isr); 

    String str1 = "012649-99999";
    String str2 = "012650-99999";
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] record = str.split("\t");
        table.put(record[0], record[1]);
    }           
    String stationName1 = table.get(str1);
    String stationName2 = table.get(str2);

} catch(...)
```

Snd the content of `station.txt` is as follows:

```
012649-99999    SIHCCAJAVRI
012650-99999    TRNSET-HANSMOEN
```

When I run the program, the stationName1 is always null, and the stationName2 can get value `012650-99999`. Who can tell me why this happen? Thank you in advance!

@matt: Yes, that's right, when I changed the encoding from 'UTF-8' to 'ANSI', it worked, stationName1 can get value, but why 'UTF-8' does not work for this situation? I always use that format.

Comment: You should use a HashMap for one thing. How about you print record[0] and record[1] when you're populating your map. Make sure what is going in there is what you think it is.

Comment: 1) Use a `HashMap<String, String>`. 2) program to the `interface` so `Map<X,Y> = new HashMap<>()`. 3) Why don't you print the contents of the `Map` to see what's in there? You might need to `trim()`.

Comment: I can make sure the record[0] and record[1] is what I think and what I want, I have printed it to the Console.

Comment: If it prints what you want, then your error is somewhere else. You can also check `record[0].equals(str2);` it should equal on of those inputs. Otherwise, you have left out too much of your problem for anybody to help you. Where do you check for null?

Comment: I just runned your program and it works fine. So looks like you have wrong input data

Comment: As per your edit, it sounds like your file is not being broken into lines correctly. You might have to check the file encoding/ line endings.

Comment: @matt, you are right, it is format reason, do you know why?

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy, in my machine, 'ANSI' works fine but 'UTF-8' does not , is your machine contrary to me?

Comment: @Coinnigh, it does not depends on machine. It depends only by encoding of input file. By default Java always uses UTF-8, but your file (written, as I understand in excel or notepad, isn't it?) is saved in ANSI encoding. That's why you had this trouble. 
In my version, of course, input file was UTF-8, that's why I had no problem

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your text file doesn't contain any `\t` character. There are multiple spaces. The correct way is to use `\\s+`, that matches mutliple whitespaces.

```
String[] record = str.split("\\s+");
```

---

Moreover `Hashtable` is obsolete. There is `HashMap<>` instead now. Here is the full code working for me. I have tested it:

```
String str;
HashMap<String, String> table = new HashMap<>();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("station.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 

String str1 = "012649-99999";
String str2 = "012650-99999";

while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] record = str.split("\\s+");
    table.put(record[0], record[1]);
}           
System.out.println(table.get(str1));
System.out.println(table.get(str2));
```

Comment: I have tried the code String[] record = str.split("\\s+");just now but the result is same.

Comment: I have tried right now and works for me. See my full code above. It's simply cannot be null. Do you read from the correct file?

Comment: Yes, the file format is not proper, when I changed the encoding from 'UTF-8' to 'ANSI', it worked, stationName1 can get value, but why 'UTF-8' does not work for this situation? I always use that format.

Comment: @Coinning, you need to understand what is encoding at all. UTF-8 here works fine... when input file is UTF-8 encoded. But your file is ANSI file, not UTF8. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please replace your following line:

```
 String[] record = str.split("\t");
```

by following line:

```
String[] record = str.split("[\\s]+");
```

and see the result?

Your working solution is here:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String str = "";
            Hashtable< String, String> table = new Hashtable< String, String>();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Dave\\Desktop\\station.txt");// FileInputStream

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 

            String str1 = "012649-99999";
            String str2 = "012650-99999";
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
                String[] record = str.split("[\\s]+");
                table.put(record[0], record[1]);
            } 
            br.close();
            String stationName1 = table.get(str1);
            String stationName2 = table.get(str2);

            System.out.println("stationName1:"+stationName1);//
            System.out.println("stationName2:"+stationName2);//
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the file contains TAB space, the correct way to match will be as follows.

```
String[] record = str.split("\\t");
```

The argument to `split()` is a regex and the regex for TAB space is `\t` which as a Java String will be `"\\t"`.

Also, don't use `Hashtable`, use `HashMap` instead as explained in the other answer.

Comment: split with only one slash works fine too. However and of course, two slashes is better

Comment: I am not the down-voter but it does not work either.